# SAP GUI Scripting API FocusChanged event call several times in C# core

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I use the SAP GUI Scripting API, I implemented the `FocusChanged` event of `GuiSession`, I focus in the X field, it comes to the function several times.

How many times does it reach the function for each focus?

What is the solution to reach it once or ignore multiple calls?

In windows C# core it's declared:

```
GuiSession.FocusChanged += GuiSession_FocusChange;
  private static void GuiSession_FocusChange(GuiSession Session, GuiVComponent NewFocusedControl)
  {
    ....
  }
```